# R avoid a for loop using an apply

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a problem like this. I managed it using this kind of statement but it's to slow. Can I improve the performance using an apply function?

```
x<-matrix(sample(1:100,40),20,2)
x<-as.data.frame(x)
for ( i in 1:nrow(x))
{
  if ( x[i,1]>x[i,2] ){
    x[i,3]<-1
  } else {
    x[i,3]<-0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need explicit or implicit looping; just use `ifelse`:

```
x[, 3] <- ifelse(x[, 1] > x[, 2], 1, 0)
```

And in fact, you can simplify this even further:

```
x[, 3] <- x[, 1] > x[, 2]
```

This will create a column that is logical rather than numeric, but for most purposes that's close enough. If not, you can convert the logical back to numeric:

```
x[, 3] <- as.numeric(x[, 1] > x[, 2])
```

Comment: On my machine, this is about 10 times faster